# Best way to get ckeditor textarea value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am not assured and really curious about this method of getting ckeditor value both are working well

> bigMsg_Value = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
>
> var htmldata = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.getBody().getHtml();

data that I get from both of that are seems like no difference, I wanna know which one is better and why.

Comment: I believe one is a shorthand for the other. Lots of little calls like that. Some are deprecated some are to be removed, etc.. I use getData().

Answer (score 0):

**`getData()` in ckeditor library:**

```
getData: function( isSnapshot ) {
    var data = this.getHtml();

    if ( !isSnapshot )
        data = this.editor.dataProcessor.toDataFormat( data );

    return data;
}
```

As you can see internally ckeditor uses `getHtml()`. As per my opinion using `getData()` will be best as it is provided by the library.